# GPU affinity (GPU core affinity)

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

Can any one tell me why there are no GPU affinity (I mean execution units affinity) ? I know in Opencl specification 1.2  we have something called device fission, but in the best of my knowledge this is juste available for CPU.

any one have more informations about this?

Thanks

Comment: Erm... if there's no such thing, what's [this extension](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/WGL_nv_gpu_affinity.txt) for? )

Comment: @raina77ow That's for allowing a (graphics) program to associate itself with a particular GPU in a system with multiple GPUs.  I believe this question is focused on why (compute) code running on a GPU is not explicitly allowed to bind itself with particular execution units inside that GPU.

Comment: First of all, why would you want affinity with particular execution units?  Affinity is normally something that is desirable in asymmetric or non-uniform systems.  From a GPU compute programmer's perspective, it should be assumed that compute code running on a GPU has symmetric, uniform access to resources, regardless of which particular execution unit(s) it is on.  While that may not be perfectly true in all cases or arguable in some cases, the reason to have that outlook is for scalability to future architectures.  The programmer should be encouraged to write code that scales with new GPUs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For me i'm looking for Affinity beacause it gives me precise handling of the GPU, and i can benchmark the hardware with more accuracy.

Comment: also it's very useful for running  more than one simultaneous kernel on one GPU.

Comment: Certainly you don't need additional constructs to run more than one simultaneous kernel.  And you're likely to have lower overall performance of you (could) bind kernel code to particular execution units.  The GPU hardware scheduler will be a better judge of that.  Of the 3 reasons listed in the cl fission extension, the only one that does not seem circular to me is the first one, to reserve capability for high-priority traffic.  Subdividing the device may not be the best way to do that, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a very CPU-related extension. I believe that some GPUS will support this soon, and there would be a couple already with the extension enabled. If you read the page below you will see some CPU features, like whenever NUMA is mentioned.

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/ext/cl_ext_device_fission.txt

Comment: I agree with you, but i'm stunned why this is not already the case! we must wait and see?